# Vertically line up input fields by proper text wrapping

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create some registration box that has label and input that are always horizontally aligned. For that I've used list elements, where each list contains label and input.

```css
    #container {
     background-color: rgb(229, 229, 229);
    }
    
    #lcontainer {
     list-style-type: none;
    }
    
    #lcontainer li {
     width: 100%;
     white-space: nowrap;
    }
    #lcontainer li label {
     word-break: break;
     white-space: pre-wrap;
    }
    #lcontainer li input {
     display: inline-block;
     white-space: normal;
    }
```

```html
 <div id="container">
     <ul id="lcontainer">
      <li>
       <label>some text</label>
       <input></input>
      </li>
      <li>
       <label>some bigger text</label>
       <input></input>
      </li>
      <li>
       <label>some bigger bigger text</label>
       <input></input>
      </li>
      <li>
       <label>some bigger bigger bigger text</label>
       <input></input>
      </li>
      <li>
       <label>some smaller one</label>
       <input></input>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
```

As visible, labels have different width's but text fields must have equal width.

---

First problem was that at certain size of `ul`, `input` element wraps. I only needed a label to wrap, so I've utilized a `white-space` property, but unfortunately it had no effect (even when display property of elements were `inline-block`)

How can I line up input elements without them being wrapped (so only label wrapping is responsible for equally lining input elements)?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you using any css framework ?

Comment: @NanditaAroraSharma No, It's just standard css3.

Comment: so you want label and input into one line ?

Comment: add some of your related css

Comment: @patelarpan Yes, added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what u want?

I have made both input and label

```
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
```

I also gave the labels fixed width, so that the inputs are aligned properly.

```css
#container {
  background-color: rgb(229, 229, 229);
}

#lcontainer {
  list-style-type: none;
}

#lcontainer li {}

#lcontainer li label {}

#lcontainer li input {}

label {
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}

input {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <ul id="lcontainer">
    <li>
      <label>some text</label>
      <input/>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>some bigger text</label>
      <input/>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>some bigger bigger text</label>
      <input/>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>some bigger bigger bigger text</label>
      <input/>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>some smaller one</label>
      <input/>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! yes, that is what I was looking for.